# Creating a custom constructor without directly calling inherited

Tags: delphi

Is it ok if in my custom constructor I don't call directly inherited but instead I call the 'normal' constructor?

```
 TContainer = Class(TNGContainer)
  private
    FEncoding: TMyEncoding;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create;   overload;    override;
    constructor Create(Enc: TMyEncoding);  overload;
  end;


constructor TContainer.Create;     { 'normal' constructor }
begin
 inherited Create;
 Clear;
 BufMaxSeqLen       := 8*KB;
 FEncodingOffset    := 33;
 {More stuff to initialize here...}
end;


constructor TContainer.Create(Enc: TMyEncoding);    { New constructor }
begin
 Create;              { Call 'normal' constructor which will call Inherited }
 Encoding:= Enc;
end;
```

I could call inherited in the second constructor but the first constructor has lots of initialization code. So, I would have to duplicate this code in both constructors. It will be easy to modify the initialization code in one constructor and forget to do the same in the other constructor.

I ran the code line by line and the constructors are called in the correct order. The inherited (parent) constructor is called correctly.

---

Pieter B's comment made me ask this 'in conclusion' question: **what makes constructor a constructor?**
The fact that it starts with keyword constructor or the fact that it calls inherited (calling the constructor in the parent object)?

Comment: What makes you doubt?

Comment: You could factor out the common initialisation code into its own procedure that could be called from both constructors.

Comment: @KeithMiller-Yes, it is true. But I like to put this (the constructor that doesn't have a direct call to inherited inside) under discussion.

Comment: @PieterB-I don't know if there are any mandatory conditions about a constructor to have 'inherited' in it. The code works perfectly but I didn't wanted to get bitten later with some nasty hard to find bug.

Comment: What makes constructor a constructor ? Just the `constructor` keyword :-) And you don't have to call `inherited` if you don't want to call ancestor's constructor.

Comment: @TLama-So, 'inherited' plays no role in the **definition** of 'constructor'?

Comment: That is the pattern I usually use when introducing new constructor overloads and I found it works well, especially when some base class has the default constructor virtual. However in some cases I revert it and the default constructor calls the one with the parameters and passes a default value and that one then does call `inherited Create` then

Comment: This is a normal pattern, I use it all the time...

Comment: @Altar, that's right, inherited doesn't define a constructor. In this case it only instructs the compiler to run the ancestor's constructor code, which is needed in most of the cases, but not necessary.

Comment: TLama, please make an answer :) (so we can have closure)

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly valid.  Even the RTL/VCL itself uses this same technique in places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly acceptable. In fact, in this case calling `inherited Create` in your new constructor would be bad and expose you to a risk of subclass's overridden constructors not being called when they should.

Assuming a hierarchy: TSubContainer = class(TContainer) = class(TNGContainer):

As you've written it (which is correct) the sequence of steps would be as follows when your new constructor is called:

- TContainer.Create(Enc: TMyEncoding);
- TSubContainer.Create;
- TContainer.Create; (assuming TSubContainer calls inherited)
- TNGContainer.Create;

If you had instead called inherited Create, the sequence of steps would be as follows:

- TContainer.Create(Enc: TMyEncoding);
- TNGContainer.Create;

Note that any work that ***should be*** done in `TSubContainer.Create;` and `TContainer.Create;` will not happen.